# How to create .vcf file having multiple contacts in Php

Tags: php, vcf-vcard

I want to create vcard of multiple contacts in single file. So If in just single install I will be able to import all contacts.

I am able to create .vcf file with single contact.
How can I generate same with multiple contacts.

I am using [this library](https://github.com/jeroendesloovere/vcard)

Comment: After a quick look at the github page, I don't think it can save multiple contact in one vCard. I see it can prase multiple though.

Comment: Can you suggest any other library with such functionality.

Comment: There is a quickfix. Generate all the vcf files. Simply read the files and append them together into one. 
Though better would be that you simply read the contents after creating your vfc and do not write them to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I use.

```
$vcard = "";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Get contact information from the database
    $name = $row['name'];
    $email = $row["email"];
    $phone = $row["wa_no"];

    // Split the name into individual words
    $nameParts = explode(' ', $name);

    // Get the last name
    $lastName = array_pop($nameParts);

    // Set the first name and middle name
    $firstName = '';
    $middleName = '';

    // If there are remaining name parts after removing the last name
    if (!empty($nameParts)) {
        // The first part is the first name
        $firstName = array_shift($nameParts);

        // The remaining parts (if any) are the middle name
        $middleName = implode(' ', $nameParts);
    }

    // Create a new vCard entry
    $vcard .= "BEGIN:VCARD\r\n";
    $vcard .= "VERSION:3.0\r\n";
    $vcard .= "N:$lastName;$middleName;$firstName;SL365 ;\r\n";
    $vcard .= "FN:$name-SL365\r\n";
    $vcard .= "TEL;type=CELL;waid=$phone:" . substr($phone, 0, 2) . " " . substr($phone, 2) . "\r\n";
    $vcard .= "EMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:$email\r\n";
    $vcard .= "END:VCARD\r\n";
}

// Set the HTTP headers to download the vCard file
$today = date("YmdHis");
header("Content-Type: text/x-vcard");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=SLcontacts$today.vcf");

// Output the vCard data
echo $vcard;
```